# How to burn a bootloader to non-bootloaded(clean crystal) ATMEGA328P-PU with USBASP programmer via Avrdudess?

Tags: atmega328, bootloader, avrdude, usbasp

I'm trying to burn bootloader to my clean crystals, atmega328p-pu.For this I use the 16MHZ crystal with two ceramic capacitors and USBASP programmer, on Windows 10 Pro. As program for burning I tried: Arduino IDE, AVRDUDESS,AVRDUDEPROG. But when I would to detect my chip(or in IDE try to burn the Chip)., I get this error:
`
avrdude.exe: set SCK frequency to 1500000 Hz
avrdude.exe: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude.exe: error: program enable: target doesn't answer. 1 
avrdude.exe: initialization failed, rc=-1
             Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
             this check.

avrdude.exe done.  Thank you.

`
From this error I understand that the target(My chips) Wouldn't to start. I checked my connection for 1000 times and I tested mt wires too, they works correctly. And supply 5V comes o chip and it become warm(it means that supply comes and it should start). I have got 5 chips And I tested all of them. I searched internet but nothing.

Please,help me, and say how can I burn them.

Best Regards,
E.M.

Comment: My understanding of that error message is that your USBASP is unable to set the right clock speed. Maybe it's got inferior (out-dated) firmware on it...

Comment: Not only. In khazarma or in avrdudeprog it don't work too

Comment: It without the bootloader. And

Comment: Have you tried with another programmer? Like I said: the error looks to pertain to the programmer, not the software or the chip.

Comment: So can I use the Arduino As ISP? If yes should I change the SPI_CLOCK to (16000000/6) as I use the 16 MHZ crystal? And which baudrate should I use:19200,115200,1000000? in ArduinoISP sketch?

Comment: don't change the Arduino as ISP sketch. select Uno in Tools menu to burn the bootloader. Uno has a 16 MHz oscillator

Comment: I'm intrigued to know what a "clean crystals atmega328p-pu" is...

Comment: it worked!!!. I took of the capacitors that was connected to crystal 16MHZ, that connected to the common GND of Arduino. So and I changed in sketch and defined the Old Wiring that I used it and it worked!!! And one more question. Why the capacitors are changed this results?

Comment: clean crystals atmega328p-pu is non-bootloaded chips